# Supabase Self Hosted responded with 404

Tags: docker, docker-compose, self-hosting, supabase

I've tried following the guide provided on supabase:
https://supabase.io/docs/guides/self-hosting

I went with Option 1 & 2 in which both resulted in the same error 404 when I try to reach localhost:8000/v1?APIKEY=.

```
192.168.32.1 - - [17/Jun/2021:07:32:29 +0000] "GET /v1 HTTP/1.1" 404 48 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.106 Safari/537.36"
```

Or perhaps there isn't a management page like the hosted one?

Here are my started containers.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top of the page you linked to:

> The self-hosted version of Supabase does not include a UI yet. We are working on this in stages, starting with our UI library (more context).

They recommend various Postgres clients as alternatives.